# How can I position objects in a circular motion from the inspector

Tags: unity

From the image below, I would like to position copies of my original circle (which is at the center) that are 1 unit away from the center and 30 degrees from each other in a circular motion. I would like to do this in the inspector. How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: When you say in the Inspector, are you looking for a sequence of manual actions you can take in the existing editing tools while building your scene to make this structure? Or do you need a script that automates this layout?

Comment: @DMGregory I would like to achieve the former, using existing editor tools to position game objects in a circular way in my scene. I guess the main thing would be how to get the positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new empty game object and position it at the location of your inner disc.
2. Duplicate your inner disc (select it and press Ctrl/Command+D) and drag it under the empty game object in the hierarchy to make it a child of this parent.
3. In the inspector, move this child disc to position (1, 0, 0) - now it's the desired 1 unit away from the center.
4. Select the parent object and duplicate it. In the inspector, set the parent's rotation to (0, 0, 30). This makes a third disc 30 degrees away from the first.
5. Keep duplicating the parent and rotating each copy through 30 degree increments until you've completed your ring.
6. Expand all the parents in the hierarchy and select the discs inside. Drag them out from under the parents back to the containing level of the hierarchy. They'll automatically keep their positions consistent in their new home in the hierarchy.
7. While you still have all the discs of the ring selected, set their rotation in the inspector to (0, 0, 0) if you want them all oriented the same as the center disc.
8. Delete the now empty parent objects - they were just helpers to create the layout and we don't need them anymore.